# Cannot resolve schema 'dbo'

Tags: hibernate

I have the following Hibernate property:

```
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">dbo</prop>
```

This was working fine with Hibernate 3, but not with Hibernate 4 (or 5) for that matter.  Why is that?

I'm using SQLServer as the DBMS.

Here is the full set of properties:

```
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">dbo</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.debug}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.debug}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.debug}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">100</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate.statistics}</prop>
            <prop key="org.ehcache.configurationResourceName">
                ehcache.xml
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>         <!-- false by default -->
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>  <!-- true by default -->
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
                org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

Comment: which database? how you are using the code. Please share.

Comment: Why do you want to use it?

Comment: @RobertNiestroj I want to use it because it was used before and I am trying to migrate from Spring 3 to Spring 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key has changed:

```
            <prop key="spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema">dbo</prop>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this with hibernate 4 or 5 and SQL Server (2008+) and it worked with dbo without this property set. Maybe because i had set dbo as the default schema on the sql server user which i used to connect to the DB.

Also consider to use a newer SQLServerDialect.